# reading a text file row wise and printing the same on html page

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, filereader

I am having text file with some data like PASS/FAIL/TestName. I need to read the data from text file(row wise) and print the same on html page using Java .

Please do the needful.

Thanks and Regards,
Bhaskar

Comment: Post your code. Maybe i could look at it and  help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below function :-

```
public String getXLcellValue(String xlpath, String sheetName, int rowNum, int cellNum)
{
    try{
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);

        Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

        return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return "";
}
```

ABove function will return that data from excel sheet

- xlpath :- path of excel
- sheetname :- sheet name of excel
- rowNum :- row number you want
- cell num :- column number you want

You need to call this function again and again till your all cell data is not complete.

Use POI jars of apache.

https://poi.apache.org/download.html

Hope it will help you :)